# Javascript, Array no longer array when passed into function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to write a script that displays a series of client testimonials, toggling the visibility of each one in order. I'm trying to use a queue to do this, and was told to use a regular Javascript array, which has the methods `push()` and `shift()` that enable queue functionality. However, when I try to pass the array into the function I wrote, I get this error:

```
TypeError: q.shift is not a function
```

So, somehow, the array I'm passing into the function is no longer an array somehow. Can someone more experienced with Javascript explain why this is happening?

Code:

```
function testimonials(q) {
       var e = q.shift();

       jQuery(e).fadeToggle("slow", testimonials(q.push(e)));

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var elements = jQuery(".fade-text").toArray();

    var queue = [];

    // add to queue
    for (i = 0; i  < elements.length; i++) {
        queue.push(elements[i]);
    }

    testimonials(queue);
});
```

Comment: what is it if you do `console.log(q)`?

Comment: It gives me the array, so it is getting passed into the function.

Comment: See if `queue` is set  immediately before you invoke `testimonials(queue)`.  Also see if `elements` is set correctly.

Comment: what is the output if you do `console.log(queue);` right above `testimonials(queue);` and `console.log(q);` right above `var e = q.shift();`?

Comment: The issue appears to be testimonials(q.push(e)), since push does not return an array, rather the new length of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the problem `testimonials(q.push(e))`, the return value of `push` is a number and that doesn't have a method called `shift()`.

```
 jQuery(e).fadeToggle("slow",function(){ testimonials((q.push(e), q)) });
```

Also you are not using the *callBack* of `fadeToggle` properly, you are calling the function `testimonials` immediately. Wrap that function call in an anonymous function and pass it as a callBack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(e).fadeToggle("slow",function(){ testimonials((q.push(e), q)) });
```